# How to make A Spinner access the other Spinner?

Tags: android-spinner

I have Three Spinners= spinState,spinCounty,& spinCity, i would like to select the State spinner then choose a State,then the second spinner would give me the list of Counties within that particular state,then select the County,then the third spinner would give me a list of the cities with in that particular county,such as: (State)Florida,(County)Dade,(City)Miami then after all 3 have been selected pass that information to the next Activity/Class. Can anyone help? here is my code

```
Spinner spinState,spinCounty,spinCity;
Button bNext;

protected void onCreate(Bundle)
{
    //TODO Auto generated method stub
    super.oncreate(Bundle)
    setContentView(R.layout.info);

    Spinner States = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinState);
    ArrayAdapter USstates = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.States, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    USstates.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    States.setAdapter(USstates);
    Spinner Counties = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCounty);
    ArrayAdapter UScounties = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.Counties, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    UScounties.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Counties.setAdapter(UScounties);
    Spinner Cities = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCity);
    ArrayAdapter UScities = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.Cities,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    UScities.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Cities.setAdapter(UScities);

    initialize();
    bNext.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

What code should i use and where?PS. whoever may answer could u use my exact variables so i won't be confused,Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
countries.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> stateadapter=null;
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                 stateadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        activityclass.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Arrays
                                .asList(getResources().getStringArray(
                                        R.array.USAstate)));
                states.setAdapter(stateadapter);
            case 1:
                 stateadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        activityclass.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Arrays
                                .asList(getResources().getStringArray(
                                        R.array.Indiastate)));
                states.setAdapter(stateadapter);
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

Select State

> ```
> <string-array name="USAstate">
>     <item>california</item>
>     <item>texas</item>
>     <item>virgina</item>
>     <item>alaska</item>          
> </string-array>
> ```